# UNIONを使ったSELECT文で、プレースホルダーを使用すると、syntaxエラーになってしまいます。

Tags: php, mysql

UNIONを使ったSELECT文で、プレースホルダーを使用すると、syntaxエラーになってしまいます。

プレースホルダーを使わない、以下のコードではエラーがでません。

```
  function getContents($page)
  {
    $limit = 3;
    $offset = $limit * $page - $limit;

    $sql = "(SELECT * FROM casper LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0) UNION ALL
            (SELECT * FROM gasper LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0) UNION ALL
            (SELECT * FROM jasper LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0) UNION ALL
            (SELECT * FROM masper LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0) UNION ALL
            (SELECT * FROM rasper LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0)
            ORDER BY title ASC";

    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
  }
```

しかし、以下のコードはエラーになります。

```
  function getContents($page)
  {
    $limit = 3;
    $offset = $limit * $page - $limit;

    $sql = "(SELECT * FROM casper LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset) UNION ALL
            (SELECT * FROM gasper LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset) UNION ALL
            (SELECT * FROM jasper LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset) UNION ALL
            (SELECT * FROM masper LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset) UNION ALL
            (SELECT * FROM rasper LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset)
            ORDER BY title ASC";

  　    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
  }
```

エラー内容は以下です。

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''3' OFFSET '0') UNION ALL
            (SELECT * FROM jasper LIMIT '3' OFFSET '0' at line 2' in /var/www/html/class/Jk.php:51
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/class/Jk.php(51): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 /var/www/html/index.php(5): Jk->getVideos(1)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/class/Jk.php on line 51
```

プレースホルダーを使っても、結果的にはプレースホルダーを使わず、値を直接している方法と同じになるはずだと思うのですが、なぜエラーになるのでしょうか？

環境に以下になります。

CentOS 6.6
PHP 5.3.3
MySQL 5.1.73

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `$stmt->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);` を `$stmt->bindValue(':limit', intval($limit), PDO::PARAM_INT);` としてみるとどうなりますでしょうか？（`$offset`も同様に）

Comment: `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` 的なことが出来ればいけそうですかね？ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーになるのはメッセージにある実SQLの

> SELECT * FROM jasper LIMIT '3' OFFSET '0'

に含まれる`LIMIT`および`OFFSET`での文字列型からの暗黙変換が許可されていないからです。

なのでheliac2001さんの言うように`intval($limit)`とか`(int)$limit`で明示的に変換すれば数値扱いになるかもしれません。

Comment: ちょっと補足すると、PDOのbindValueの第三引数でPDO::PARAM_INTを指定していているのに文字列と扱われているのはなぜか、これに何の意味があるかというと、現状ではboolをintには変換するがそれ以外は何もしないということのようです。したがって、bindValueで「正しく」数値を渡すには第二引数は自分で数値に変換し、第三引数にはPDO::PARAM_INTを指定することの両方が必要です。参考 http://blog.a-way-out.net/blog/2013/12/18/pdo-prepare-statement-numeric-literal-part2/

Comment: (int)、intvalを使用しても、同じエラーが出てしまい、文字列として認識しているようです。
しかし、UNIONを使用せず、対象のテーブルを1つにして実行していみると、(int)、intvalを使用した場合も、使用しない場合も正しく実行されます。UNIONになんからの原因があるのでしょうか？

Comment: (int)、intvalを使用し、@ohgaさんのコメント通り、setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false)と指定すると、以下のエラーに変化しました。

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number'

setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false)を指定した場合も同様にUNIONを使わない場合は、エラーがも表示されず、正しく実行されました。

上記エラーは引数の数が正しくないという意味だと認識していますが、UNIONを使用した場合のbindValueの使用には特別な方法が必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: @sleepingDead 実際のところMySQL自体がプリペアドステートメントの名前付き引数に対応していないので、PDOのモードに関わらずクライアント上でのエミュレーションは発生します。いずれにせよ明らかにドライバ側の問題なので、バインドは諦めて`$limit`,`$offset`と埋め込むしかないように思います。

Comment: @pgrho ドライバの問題なんですね。
疑問符パラメータを使用すると、うまくいったので、これで対応してみます。